# Issues with adding color to dynamically created pictureboxes in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add some life and color to dynamically created pictureboxes in panel.

I write this code:

```
Panel panel_main = new Panel();
this.Controls.Add(panel_main);
panel_main.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
panel_main.BackColor = Color.Black;

PictureBox[] logos = new PictureBox[6];

for (int i  = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    this.Controls.Add(logos[i]);
    logos[i] = new PictureBox();
    logos[i].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    logos[i].Location = new Point(i * 10, i * 10);
    logos[i].Size = new Size(i * 40, i * 10);
    logos[i].Visible = true;
}
```

pictureboxes are shown on screen, but nor size, nor color appears correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this.Controls.Add(logos[i]); // logos[i] is null yet
logos[i] = new PictureBox();
logos[i].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
logos[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
// 1. add pictureBoxes into panel
// 2. add pictureBoxes after you created them, not before
panel_main.Controls.Add(logos[i]);
```

[image]

Comment: @ZygmuntKołodziejczyk, `@nikolifish` points in his answer that `logos[0]` has zero size. you might want to fix it as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues here.

First, you're adding nothing on this line

```
this.Controls.Add(logos[i]);
```

move this line to the bottom of your loop.

Second, your first box has zero size, that may not actually be an issue, but just so you know.

Third is how you're adding the control.

```
this.Controls.Add(logos[i]);
```

This will put the picturebox on the Form.  My intution suggests that you actually want to use

```
panel_main.Controls.Add(logos[i]);
```

to add it to the panel rather than the form.  If you really do want to use the form, after you add the control call BringToFront method on the picturebox.

```
logos[i].BringToFront();
```

Comment: main issue was declaring picturebox to panel before it was created